# CakePHP 2: Acl tutorial doesn't work

Tags: cakephp, foreign-keys, acl, cakephp-2.2

as the title already says I've got a problem with the Acl Tutorial of CakePHP 2.
I've done everything exactly the way it is mentioned in the Tutorial, but still it doesn't work.

I know that there are many people on the internet which have also a problem with this tutorial, but I can't find any blog entry or whatever with the same problem like me. 
When I try to access a direction of my app I get the following error:

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: group_id [APP\Model\User.php, line 98]
```

and:

```
AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aro node identified by "Array ( [Aro0.model] => Group [Aro0.foreign_key] => ) "
```

So there isn't any value for the foreign_key transmitted to the Acl at all.
But the strange thing is that -at least in the functions of the userscontroller- the foreign_key is set properly but when it should be passed to the Acl it is gone

```
Nr  Query   Error   Affected    Num. rows   Took (ms)

1   SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake`.`users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`id` = 4
2   SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake`.`users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`id` = 4
3   SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake`.`users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`id` = 4
4   UPDATE `cake`.`users` SET `modified` = '2012-11-13 19:59:47' WHERE `cake`.`users`.`id` = '4'
5   SELECT `User`.`group_id` FROM `cake`.`users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
6   SELECT `Aro`.`id`, `Aro`.`parent_id`, `Aro`.`model`, `Aro`.`foreign_key`, `Aro`.`alias` FROM `cake`.`aros` AS `Aro` LEFT JOIN `cake`.`aros` AS `Aro0` ON (`Aro`.`lft` <= `Aro0`.`lft` AND `Aro`.`rght` >= `Aro0`.`rght`) WHERE `Aro0`.`model` = 'Group' AND `Aro0`.`foreign_key` = 2 ORDER BY `Aro`.`lft` DESC
7   SELECT `Aro`.`id`, `Aro`.`parent_id`, `Aro`.`model`, `Aro`.`foreign_key`, `Aro`.`alias` FROM `cake`.`aros` AS `Aro` LEFT JOIN `cake`.`aros` AS `Aro0` ON (`Aro`.`lft` <= `Aro0`.`lft` AND `Aro`.`rght` >= `Aro0`.`rght`) WHERE `Aro0`.`model` = 'User' AND `Aro0`.`foreign_key` = 4 ORDER BY `Aro`.`lft` DESC
8   SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake`.`aros` AS `Aro` WHERE `Aro`.`id` = 6
9   SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake`.`aros` AS `Aro` WHERE `Aro`.`id` = 6
10  SELECT `Aro`.`parent_id` FROM `cake`.`aros` AS `Aro` WHERE `Aro`.`id` = 6 LIMIT 1
11  SELECT `Aro`.`id`, `Aro`.`parent_id`, `Aro`.`lft`, `Aro`.`rght` FROM `cake`.`aros` AS `Aro` WHERE 1 = 1 AND `Aro`.`id` = 6 LIMIT 1
12  SELECT `Aro`.`id`, `Aro`.`lft`, `Aro`.`rght` FROM `cake`.`aros` AS `Aro` WHERE 1 = 1 AND `Aro`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
13  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake`.`aros` AS `Aro` WHERE `Aro`.`id` = 6
14  UPDATE `cake`.`aros` SET `parent_id` = 2, `model` = 'User', `foreign_key` = 4, `id` = 6 WHERE `cake`.`aros`.`id` = '6'
15  SELECT `Aro`.`id`, `Aro`.`parent_id`, `Aro`.`model`, `Aro`.`foreign_key`, `Aro`.`alias` FROM `cake`.`aros` AS `Aro` LEFT JOIN `cake`.`aros` AS `Aro0` ON (`Aro`.`lft` <= `Aro0`.`lft` AND `Aro`.`rght` >= `Aro0`.`rght`) WHERE `Aro0`.`model` = 'Group' AND `Aro0`.`foreign_key` IS NULL ORDER BY `Aro`.`lft` DESC
```

The lines from the error message are:

```
public function bindNode($user) {
    return array('model'=>'Group','foreign_key'=>$user['User']['group_id']);
}
```

So why is the value of the foreign_key firstly '2' (how it is supposed to be) and afterwards NULL  ?

I hope some of you are able to help me.
Thanks.

PS: For everyone who would prefer the german version of my question, [here](http://www.cakephp-forum.de/models/acl-tutorial-von-cake-lauft-nich-so-wie-es-soll-t1249.html) it is

**UPDATE:**
I was able to make it work for all functions of the userscontroller through this:

```
public function bindNode() {
    $this->id;
    $data = $this->read();
    return array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => $data['User']['group_id']);
    }
```

But for all other Controllers its still the same..
Has any one an idea how i could get the users data in the model, so that it works also for the other controllers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know its a bit stupid to answer my own question, but instead of deleting the question i think it would be better to leave it here for anybody who has the same problem, because there seems to be no answer for this on the internet.

I was able to solve the problem through the following code:

```
public function bindNode() {
    $data = AuthComponent::user();
    return array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => $data['User']['group_id']);
    }
```

It seems to work perfectly, and maybe it could help some others ;)